# Assigning links to buttons - All on same layer

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a fla/swf file, with 6 buttons on it all with their own hover effects and such, however they're all on the same layer. So assigning a link to each one through actionscript is confusing as I've only done it if they were on different layers.

Any advice as to how to achieve this? (Using Flash cs4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it does not make any difference if they are on the same layer or not. You have to assign a instance name to every button(e.g. "button01" and "button02" and then you can differentiate between them like:

```
function init():void {
    button01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK,onActionPerformed,false,0,true);
    button01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK,onActionPerformed,false,0,true);
}

function onActionPerformed(e:MouseEvent):void {
    switch(e.currentTarget) {
       case button01: navigateToUrl(/*put your link in here*/); break;
       case button02: navigateToUrl(/*Put another link in here*/); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to work out the kinks and get it all coded with no compiling errors, however none of the buttons are actually navigating to the url's....

<br>
homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed,false,0,true);
<br>
case homeButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_blank"); break;
<br>
Is the general format I followed, and the buttons instance name is renamed to homeButton.

Comment: Always put some trace('something'): function calls in your functions to see if they get called at all. If the onActionPerformed function is called once you click a button make sure one of the cases get called. Maybe e.currentTarget is not your "homeButton" or any other button you expect it to be.